# C# - Postgres - Memory leak issue over time

Tags: c#, postgresql, memory-leaks

**Problem:** The memory leaks & accumulates over time, and eventually reaches its 99% capacity

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911581/c-sharp-postgresql-memory-leak-over-time) is a question I previously asked on the same topic. I did as the guy who answered told me to do, but I am still experiencing memory leak issues. I really do not understand from where the memory is accumulating. I observed the `Windows Task Manager`, and found out that periodically memory clears, but the memory accumulation rate is faster than clearing rate, and as a result, memory capacity reaches 99% at the end.

Here is my `C#` code:

```
var connString = "Host=x.x.x.x;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=password;Database=database";
@Info.Trace("PostGre ");

using (var conn = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(connString)){

    conn.Open();

    int ctr = 0;

    // Insert some data
    using (var cmd = new Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        var par_1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@r", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp);
        var par_2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@p", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double);

        while(@tag.TerminateTimeScaleLoop == 100)
        {   
            @Info.Trace("Pushed Data: PostGre A " + ctr.ToString());

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TORQX VALUES (@r,@p)";
            par_1.Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
            par_2.Value = @Tag.RigData.Time.TORQX;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            

            ctr = ctr + 1;
        }


    }
    @Info.Trace("Pushed Data: PostGre A Terminated");
    conn.Close();              

}
```

What is causing the memory accumulation? Can I prevent it from accumulating? If preventing accumulation is impossible, can I manually clear memory? What set of codes will do that?

I have practically no experience with `C#`, and I was assigned to do a hot fix on this `C#` code because the person who wrote this code isn't available now. I have lots of experience in `Python`, but no experience with `C#`, so please give me suggestions in a really explicit way... otherwise I will have no clue. Thanks!

Comment: What do the traces do? Nothing in this piece of code should cause any persistent memory usage otherwise.

Comment: Unused memory is wasted memory. The CLR will recycle and reuse available ram as the GC heap grows. It going up to 99% is not a sign something is going wrong, especially when working with sql databases of any decent size.